# Calculate Max in value with prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Since I am prometheus-newbie I do not know how to express the question:
"What is the maximum number of messages which have been processed per second during the last day". The metric is named `messages_in_total`

I tried

- `max_over_time(messages_in_total{}[1d])` - but this returns the maximum of the counter value
- `increase(messages_in_total{}[1d])`- but this returns the number the counter increased

What I really need would be something like (pseudocode)

1. Transform range vector which contains absolute messages_in_total to a range vector with which has a value for each second.
2. get the max out out of it

Example:

- initial range vector values =  (3000,4000, 7000, 8009)
- adjusted range vector values with rate for each second (values are guessed) = (40, 70, 40)
- max_value => 70 messages processed per second

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible.

Example query:

```
max_over_time(
   irate( messages_in_total[2m] )[1d:1m]
)
```

This will:

1. take last 1 day
2. For every 1 minute in that 1 day range it will execute `irate( messages_in_total[2m] )`
3. Combine that into range vector
4. Call max_over_time on all results

See [subquery documentation](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) for more information!

Comment: With your answer and the help of the subsquery from prometheus it is now working for me. Thank you. Unfortunately prometheus always manipulates the values (I know they have to) and so i get different results for the same query each time i call it. Very annoying especially if you are learning.

Comment: @EhmKaha.k.a.MichaelKrauße, values are changed each time the query is performed because of `irate()` function. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.

Answer (score -1):

While [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64066138/274937) returns the maximum per-second rate over the last 24 hours for `messages_in_total` metric, it has the following potential issues:

- It may skip a part of raw samples if the interval between them (aka `scrape_interval`) is smaller than one minute. This can be fixed by reducing the `step` value in square brackets after the colon, so it doesn't exceed the `scrape_interval`.
- It may return an empty result or incomplete result if the scrape interval exceeds 2m (e.g. 2 minutes). This can be fixed by increasing the lookbehind window in the inner square brackets from `2m` to the value exceeding 2x `scrape_interval`.
- It may become very slow and resource hungry because of [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) overhead.
- Subqueries are easy to mis-use, so they would silently return unexpected results.

While Prometheus doesn't provide the reliable and easy to use solution for these issues, other Prometheus-like systems may have the solution. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns the maximum, the minimum and the average per-second increase rates for `messages_in_total` time series for the last 24 hours:

```
rollup_rate(messages_in_total[1d])
```

It uses [rollup_rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup_rate) function.
If you need only the maximum per-second rate, then the query can be wrapped into [label_match](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_match) function, which leaves only time series with `rollup="max"` label:

```
label_match(
  rollup_rate(messages_in_total[1d]),
  "rollup", "max"
)
```