# Getting max cpu in Prometheus guery

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, promql

How to get maximum values of CPU for each namemespace with a given time range? 
To get vectors of values I used: 
`sum(namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate{}) by (namespace)`
I am a little bit confused with `max()` and `max_over_time()` functions.
Especially I don't understand how join `max_over_time`, `sum` and `rate` functions together to achieve expected result

Comment: For this you need `max_over_time` and subquery syntax (like `[30d:]`) to allow range selector over non-trivial vector selector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Max in value with prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058630/calculate-max-in-value-with-prometheus)

Comment: I tried something like this
```max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [720h:1s])``` but I get error:
```bad_data: parse error at char 107: range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.AggregateExpr instead```

Comment: Your exact query doesn't produce this exact error. At least not in Prometheus. https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io. Are you sure you copied everything correctly? Or if you are using older version, you (maybe) need to wrap your subquery into parenthesis (like this `max_over_time( (sum(...) ) [30d:1s])`)

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the maximum sum of `namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate` metrics per `namespace` over the last hour (see `[1h]` in the query):

```
max_over_time(
  (
    sum(
      namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate
    ) by (namespace)
  )[1h:1m]
)
```

It uses [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) feature for calculating the sum of `namespace_pod_name_container_name:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate` per each `namespace` at every minute of a 1-hour time range ending at the current timestamp. Then it finds the maximum value over these calculated sums per each `namespace`.

See [max_over_time() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#max_over_time) and [sum() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) for more details.